# Прогресс бар загрузки для swf Flash

Tags: jquery, flash, progress-bar, javascript, swf

Есть Flash игра на сайте, работает хорошо, но грузится долго и в самом файле игры (game.swf) нету прогресс бара. Надо добавить его. Вмешаться в сам файл игры я не могу.
Можно ли реализовать прогресс бар загрузки через js или ещё как-то?

Answer (score 1):

Легче это сделать, сделав флешку обертку(прелоадер), который будет загружать game.swf через Loader, и в процессе загрузки показывать прогрессбар.

Код примерно следующий

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[yourdomain].com/game.swf"); 
var loader:Loader = new Loader() 
loader.load(request); 
addChild(loader);
```

После успешной загрузки внешний SWF-файл можно получить через свойство `Loader.content`

Более подробно расписано на сайте эдоба
http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d9e.html